# Comparator Using Common Gate CMOS

Tags: circuit-analysis, amplifier, analog, oscillator, cmos

I am currently in the process of designing and testing a CMOS Comparator based of a Common Gate Topology.

Below is an extract of the ref circuit I am using:

[image: Single Phase Current Mode Relaxation Oscillator]

The authors in the paper mention "Transistors M0 and M1 are each biased with a current Iref, while arranged as a source-coupled voltage comparator. One branch of Iref flows through the resistor Rref to generate a reference voltage Vref, while a second matched current flows into capacitor C and slowly charges the voltage VC. Initially, VC is reset to ground, causing Vcmp to be pulled low. Once VC exceeds Vref, M1 amplifies the voltage difference (VC−Vref) and Vcmp rises, triggering a digital clock buffer to generate a pulse Vrst which in turn resets VC. Unlike most voltage-mode relaxation oscillators, no additional comparator stage is required, thanks to the re-use of Iref for both charging the capacitor and biasing the comparator."

I'm not sure why the CG- AMP would amplify the difference between Vc and Vref, rather than just Vref, since in small signal the gate becomes shorted (unless this is large signal gain)?

It would be nice to get an intuitive understanding of what the Author means. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a large-signal effect, and in general, you'll often need large-signal effects to discuss comparators (which often turn stages fully on/off, slew them significantly, etc).

Assume that M0 and M1 are matched. The current-mirror structure around M0 sets the shared gate net to \$V_\text{ref}R_\text{ref} + V_\text{gs}\$, where \$V_\text{gs}\$ is the large-signal bias point where M0 and M1 would have a current of \$I_\text{ref}\$ flow.

When \$V_c\$ > \$V_\text{ref}\$ (in the large-signal sense), \$V_\text{gs,M1} < V_\text{gs}\$ and M1 cuts off, allowing \$V_\text{cmp}\$ to rise significantly, to nearly \$V_{DD}\$ minus the minimum voltage drop over the reference current source.

Likewise, when \$V_c\$ < \$V_\text{ref}\$, M1's \$V_\text{GS}\$ is large, M1 conducts strongly (in triode), and \$V_\text{cmp}\$ is close to ground (again, allowing for a small voltage drop across the transistor).

Small-signal analysis would be interesting for the transition point where \$V_c \approx V_\text{ref}\$. However, I would suspect that due to various saturation effects, slew rate limitations, and the time it takes to charge/discharge capacitances (not explicitly shown here), that transition point isn't so important. Once the comparator trips, I expect that S1 stays turned on long enough to discharge C so that \$V_c\$ ends up well below \$V_\text{ref}\$, and we don't spend a lot of time in that nearly-balanced, small-signal regime.

Comment: Hi There, thank for the intuitive response, it makes complete sense now. 

However would this also be true if the NMOS is working in Sub-threshold saturation, where we can conduct when VGS < Vth?

Comment: @soccernismo There is not much merit in talking about sub-threshold for large signal excitations. You aren't at some finely-balanced value between 0 and Vth where the current is exactly right. If Vgs of M1 is less than Vgs of M0 by any non-small-signal value, then M1 is going to carry less current and the output node will rise to a saturated value.